# emacs search throught rectangle

Tags: emacs

is it possible with emacs to search a specific region of text for example I have a csv file like this

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
11,11,11
11,22,3444
234,44,
```

and I want to search the content of the second column is it possible to do this with emacs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `narrow-to-region` to change the region and search within that and then use `widen`

Comment: How do you narrow to only the contents of the second column? Narrowing doesn't work with rectangle selection AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression: <kbd>C-M-s</kbd>`^[^,]*,[^,]44[^,],` to search for 44 in the second column.

See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Search.html) for help.